# Removing circular dependencies between classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, circular-dependency

Suppose we are making a two player card game, and we have classes called Game, Player, and Card. Game contains a pointer to the two players & provides an interface for the players. Player consists of the health of the player & their magic along with a vector of cards which is their hand. Card is an abstract class. Each Card costs magic to play, and can be played.

The problem is that each Card, when played, can alter the game state in any number of ways. For example, we could have a Card which doubles a player's health, a Card which poisons the enemy player for two turns, a Card which destroys all minions on the board, a Card which creates a copy of each minion already on the board, etc. The possibilities are really endless. The only solution I can see is having a pointer to Game inside each Card, but this seems rather inelegant.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Why should each card need to know the game state to affect it ? Each card would have properties \ methods which the game object would use to change its state.

Comment: If a Game owns players and Players own Cards, it seems to me that a Card can directly modify Game variables, maybe through Game methods. I may misunderstand something

Comment: its not Card responsibility to modify Game state. it is Game responsibility to modify it own state in case of witch card is been proccessed. the simple path to get it is pattern Strategy

Comment: @auburg: if you let `Game` apply behavior of `Card` through its properties you end up in a lot of spaghetti code, you must let each `Card` (or rather `Effect`) take care of itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your basic idea is correct but you should enhance it further to keep a high level of abstraction and encapsulation.

So in your example let's say you have a `Card` class which is an instance of an existing class.

The first thing you can do is to split the effect of the card from the card itself, for example:

```
class CardEffect {
 // TODO ...
};

class Card {
private:
  const CardEffect* effect;
};
```

So now the card itself doesn't need to know anything about the game. But let's get deeper into this: a `CardEffect` doesn't need to know every detail of `Game` class, what it needs to be able to do is to apply effects to the game. This can be done by providing a separate interface to the effect which only exposes what's needed to apply the effect, so something like this.

```
class GameInterface {
public:
  virtual const std::vector<Player*>& getPlayers() = 0;

  virtual damagePlayer(Player* player, int amount) = 0;
  virtual applyPeriodicDamage(Player* player, int turns, int amount) = 0

  ..
};

class CardEffect {
  virtual applyEffect(GameInterface* interface) = 0;
};

class Card {
private:
  const CardEffect* effect;
};
```

Now this is just an example, there's no definitive solution to your problem since each specific scenario is different and has different requirements, it's just to give you a basic idea in how you could try to keep code elegant and encapsulated while keeping it enough descriptive to be easy to manage.

Comment: Thanks! I'd thought about doing that, but then one problem is that if I want to add a new Card, I may have to change gameInterface as well as create a class for that Card whereas if I use a game pointer, I only have to do the latter.. still, I agree that this is a much nicer way (though I don't see why the functions in GameInterface are pure virtual..)

Comment: Because you could have a `LocalGame : public GameInterface` or maybe a `RemoteGame : public GameInterface` which implement features differently. Having a pure interface is just simpler. You don't add a new `Card`, you implement a new `CardEffect`. `Card` stay the same as it's using effect by composition. So that you could do `Card* card = new Card(new MyEffect()), card2 = new Card(new MyEffect2());` With `std::function` you could directly have a `std::function<void(GameInterface*)>` and forget about a lot of memory management.

Comment: But I would still have to alter GameInterface if I wanted a new Card, right? I could decide I want to add a Card which allows minions to cleave upon attack, and if this isn't in GameInterface, then I would have to implement it there. 

Also, shouldn't there be a public method within Card which calls effect->applyEffect? But then this method would be calling a pure virtual function.. does C++ allow that? The only other option I see would be to make the CardEffect a public field of Card, which should be fine since we've declared it const

Comment: You need to provide `GameInterface` for the building blocks necessary for your effects to be implemented. For such an effect to be implemented you'd need an `CardEffect::onMinionAttack(GameInterface* game, Minion* attacker, Minion* defender)` called by the game logic which would do something `auto nears = game->getMinionsNearToMinion(defender); ...`. It's not easy to design a proper system and it really depends on what you need.

Comment: Thanks. Lastly, how would we pass in pointers to Players within GameInterface? For example, if we wanted to create a concrete CardEffect which decreases the enemy player's health by 10, we would need a pointer to that player. It would be something like : Game receives input to play the card -> Game tells the active player to play the card -> The player calls the cardEffect's applyEffect method, but what would the function body of this look like? I think we would need to keep pointers to both players within GameInterface..

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have a cross dependencies like:

```
class Card
{
   Game* game;
   void f() {
     game->method1();
   }
}; 

class Game
{
   std::vector<Card> cards;
 public:
   void method1();
};
```

One of the dependencies should implement an interface like:

```
class IGame
{
 public:
   virtual void method1()=0;
};

class Card
{
  IGame* game;
  void f() {
     game->method1();
   }
}; 

class Game : public IGame
{
   std::vector<Card> cards;
 public:
   virtual void method1();
};
```

And as you can see no more cross dependencies.

Comment: A cross dependency doesn't imply the requirement of an interface. Forward declarations and separating code from header and source would be enough, you want an interface for abstraction, it's not just used to solve a compilation problem.

Comment: @jack Any cross dependency is a design problem. the problem may be covered in several ways, like you mentioned, but it still a design problem. many patterns are dealing with avoiding the circular dependencies, like observer and more.

Comment: @SHR Then would I have to make a new class for each Card? For example, for Card_1 I create IGame_1, Card_2 -> IGame_2 etc?

Comment: @Saad You don't have to, it is your choice. All `Card` actions can be in single `IGame` interface. You can also set one method with `Card&` as parameter, and the `Game` may decide what to do according to the given `Card`.